# Error with input dimension

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to implement a custom rbf kernel function. However I am getting the following error. I am not sure why it is expected a certain amount of data points?
Error occurs in this line of code:

```
rbf_y = rbf_kernel.predict(X_test)
```

Code

```
def myKernel(x,y):
    pairwise_dists = squareform(pdist(x, 'euclidean'))
    K = scip.exp(-pairwise_dists ** 2 / .08 ** 2)
    return K

rbf_kernel = svm.SVC(kernel=myKernel, C=1).fit(X_train, Y_train.ravel())
rbf_y = rbf_kernel.predict(X_test)
rbf_accuracy = accuracy_score(Y_test, rbf_y)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 15510 should be equal to 31488, the number of samples at training time
```

Data Shape

```
X_train shape:  (31488, 128)
X_test shape:  (15510, 128)
Y_train shape:  (31488, 1)
Y_test shape:  (15510, 1)
```

Return Shape from Kernel

```
myKernel(X_train, X_train).shape = (31488, 31488)
```

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

A custom kernel `kernel(X, Y)` should compute a similarity measure between the matrix `X` and the matrix `Y`, and the output should be of shape `[X.shape[0], Y.shape[0]]`. Your kernel function ignores `Y`, and returns a matrix of shape `[X.shape[0], X.shape[0]]`, which leads to the error you are seeing.

To fix the issue, implement a kernel function that computes a kernel matrix of the correct shape. Scikit-learn's [custom kernels documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/svm.html#custom-kernels) has some simple examples of how this might work.

In the case of your specific kernel, you might try `cdist(x, y)` in place of `squareform(pdist(x))`.